# Bash capture any error like -e but don't exit, do something else

Tags: bash, shell-script, error-handling

I want to set a flag in a shell script (bash) so that if anything returns non-zero, a flag is set (i.e. set a variable like `errors="True"`).

So far, I've thought of calling the script with `scriptname.sh 2>Error.log` and then doing something like:

```
 if $(wc -l error.log) != 0; then
   errors="True"
```

There has got to be a much better way. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly what `trap ERR` is for. Unfortunately, it has the same limitations and drawbacks as `set -e`. Like `set -e`, any command which returns non-zero in a conditional expression will to trigger the trap. Here is some example code:

```
error=0
set_error() {
    (( error++ )) 
}

trap set_error ERR
ls askdjasdaj 2>/dev/null
false
false || true # false returns non-zero but is not counted due to the conditional
echo "$error" # outputs "2"
```

Comment: Thanks! Does trap work for any error caught below the line where trap is?  trap -l lists standard signals, I don't see ERR but ERR seems to work.  What is ERR considered to be?  Is it a signal, or is it shorthand for the file descriptor?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal - it's neither, it is special to bash. There are more details in the "trap" section of the bash manpage.

Comment: Sorry, I just read it (or have begun to read it).  I am a little confused because errtrace is not set in my shell, I thought I saw that it needed to be set for the ERR keyword to work with trap, but I may have misread that.